# How to get distinct values separately in string array?

Tags: c#, linq

i have two string array

```
string[] oldname = ["arun","jack","tom"];
string[] newname = ["jack","hardy","arun"];
```

here i want compare these two string arrays to get these distinct values separately like :

```
oldname = ["tom"];
newname = ["hardy"];
```

how to achieve these ...

Comment: Do you have to use arrays? Can you use List?

Comment: Does both array comprises of same size?

Comment: But your result doesn't show "distinct" values... If you ask distinct, the olname and newname must be printed as-is because they are "Distinct"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string[] oldNameDistinct = oldname.Where(s => !newname.Contains(s)).ToArray();
string[] newNameDistinct = newname.Where(s => !oldname.Contains(s)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Let the two arrays were defined like the following:

```
 string[] oldname = new[] { "arun", "jack", "tom" };
 string[] newname = new string[] { "jack", "hardy", "arun" };
```

Then you can use the Extension method `.Except` to achieve the result that you are looking for. Consider the following code and the [working example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vP6Mfm)

```
 var distinctInOld = oldname.Except(newname);
 var distinctInNew = newname.Except(oldname);
```

Comment: this works but I believe it leaves a gap. What if there are multiples?

Comment: @MichaelBedford: Sorry I don't get you, what would be the changes in the input? could you please try with the Working example that i have added with my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
    string[] oldname = new string[] { "arun", "jack", "tom" };
    string[] newname = new string[] { "jack", "hardy", "arun" };

    List<string> distinctoldname = new List<string>();
    List<string> distinctnewname = new List<string>();

    foreach (string txt in oldname)
    {
       if (Array.IndexOf(newname, txt) == -1)
         distinctoldname.Add(txt);
     }

     foreach (string txt in newname)
     {
        if (Array.IndexOf(oldname, txt) == -1)
          distinctnewname.Add(txt);
     }


   //here you can get both the arrays separately
```

Hope this help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] oldname = new []{"arun","jack","tom"};
string[] newname = new []{"jack","hardy","arun"};

// use linq to loop through through each list and return values not included in the other list.
var distinctOldName = oldname.Where(o => newname.All(n => n != o));
var distinctNewName = newname.Where(n => oldname.All(o => o != n));

distinctOldName.Dump(); // result is tom
distinctNewName.Dump(); // result is hardy
```